# Error in using sessions with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a simple login page which uses JS, JQuery and PHP.

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Login activity to learn AJAX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>AJAX learning</h1>
    <h2>Login below to continue</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <p>User ID:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p><input type="text" name="uid" id="usr"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Password:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p><input type="password" name="pwd"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p><input type="button" onclick="checkLogin()" value="Login"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p id="status"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

login.js

```
function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}
function checkLogin(){
    var xhttp=new ajaxRequest();
    var uid=$('input[name=uid]').val();
    var pwd=$('input[name=pwd]').val();
    xhttp.open("POST","do_login.php",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var param = "UID="+uid+"&PASS="+pwd;
    xhttp.send(param);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4){
            if(xhttp.status==200){
                generateResponse(xhttp.responseText,uid);
            }
            else{
                window.alert("Error while making request");
            }
        }
    }
}
function generateResponse(data,uid){
    if(data==="Error 1"){
        $("#status").text("USER NOT FOUND!");
        $("input[name=uid]").val("");
        $("input[name=pwd]").val("");
    }
    else if(data==="Error 2"){
        $("#status").text("INCORRECT PASSWORD!");
        $("input[name=pwd]").val("");
    }
    else{
        window.location='page2.php';
    }
}
```

do_login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $uid=$_POST['UID'];
    $pass=$_POST['PASS'];

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","shreyansh","","ajax");
    $query1 = "SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '$uid' AND pass = '$pass' ";
    $query2 = "SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,$query1));
    // checking credentials
    $response = "";
    if(count($result)==0){
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,$query2));
        if(count($res)==0){
            $response = "Error 1";
        }
        else
            $response = "Error 2";
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['username']=$uid;
    }
    echo $response;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username']))
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?> </p>
</body>
```

The main objective is to show error messages in the **login.php** page and redirect to **page2.php** if the credentials are correct.
On pressing the login button the page gets redirected to page2.php but nothing is displayed. The entire webpage is blank. Please identify the error in my code.

Comment: you forgot  to add `session_start();` on top on `do_login.php` page. remove from `else` part and add on top,and check

Comment: Tried doing that. Still does not work

Comment: Add session_start(); in do_login.php at top of the page and remove from page2.php

Comment: i said remove from `else` part and add on top in `do_login.php`

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid  it's needed on both page

Comment: @AlivetoDie No session always start at once.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid  if you want to use session on any page then you have to write `session_start();`.it's compulsary

Comment: @AlivetoDie No.

Comment: Tried removing session_start() from page2.php,still it does not work.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid  till my knowledge if you are not using frameworks+cms and you are using plain php pages like above given by OP. `session_start();` needed on each page if you want to do any stuff with `SESSION`

Comment: Please enable [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: And your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5914775). Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/5914775). Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: 1) Listen remove session_start from else and write it on the top of the page (do_login.php). 2) where you want to get a session echo your session value and you need to write session_start() function again. it is batter you create a common file and include this on all pages where you want your session.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid session start is needed

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i know on a same page no need to re declare session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION(['username'])) || empty($_SESSION['username']))
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

`$_SESSION` is not a function so using it with () will return an error. Also just a header does not prevent the page from running, so your code will still be executed. You have to prevent the code execution after setting the location header

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }
?>
```

You also have a mysql injection in your sql `"SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '$uid'"` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Try using `' or 1 or 'a` as the username

The easiest way to prevent it is to enclosure the variables passed to your query with `addslashes`:

```
"SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '" . addslashes($uid) . "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

> first of all, I **strongly** recommand that you consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Also, you should **not** store plain-text password, therefore:

> you should **really** consider using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and his fellow collegue [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Beside that, I would make your code a little different, such as :

-> modify generateResponse function as this:

```
function generateResponse(data,uid){
if(data === "Error"){
    $("#status").text("user not found : make sure you are using correct credentials.");
    $("input[name=uid]").val("");
    $("input[name=pwd]").val("");
}
else {
    window.location='page2.php';
}
}
```

-> use only **one** query (that's where PPS will be more safe)

```
<?php
session_start();

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","shreyansh","","ajax");
$query1 = "SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '$uid' AND pass = '$pass' ";
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,$query1));
// checking credentials
$response = "";
if(count($result) == 0){ $response = "Error"; } else { $_SESSION['username'] = $uid; $response = ""; }
echo $response;

?>
```

-> finally, correct the misuse of $_SESSION in page2.php (**CREDIT** goes to @Dimitri-L)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
else
{
?>
<p>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**config.php**

session_start();

DB credentials // you can also write your DB details here

**do_login.php**

include_once('config.php');

your code for login.

**page2.php**

include_once('config.php');

print_r($_SESSION);